# Angular Material Data Table not sorting?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

[[STACKBLITS LINK] I'm attempting a minimal angular material data table with sorting](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-minimal-material-table-demo-with-sorting).

I've added the MatSortModule, implemented `@ViewChild` in the class, added the directives, set the dataSource.sort property etc. and I get the arrow on the table when I mouse hover, but the data does not sort.

Thoughts?

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from "@angular/material";

    class Todo {
      id: string;
      description: string;
      complete: boolean;
    }
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

      /**
      * Control column ordering and which columns are displayed.
      */
      displayedColumns:string[] =  ['id'];
      dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Todo>;

      ngOnInit() {
        const todos: Todo[] = [
          { id: '123', description: 'Complete me!', complete: false },
          { id: '321', description: 'You Completed me!', complete: true }];
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(todos);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      }
    }


    <mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;">{{row.id}}</mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns">
      </mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ViewChild` for `MatSort` is `undefined` at `ngOnInit` since the view has not yet been initialized. To resolve this, set the `MatSort` on your `dataSource` after the view has initialized by using the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you need to set the MatSort.
 This is how I fixed it

```
@ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) set  sortMeeting (ms: MatSort){
this._sort = ms;
this.renewDataSource(); }
```

............................................

```
ngOnInit(){
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(todos);
this.renewDataSource();
}


renewDataSource() {
this.dataSource.sort = this._sort;
}
```

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: We have to wait until `AfterViewInit` in order to make sure that the `sortDirective` has been fully initialized.